# Rails tokenInput values not reloading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-tokeninput

I have implemented a token input field in my Rails 3 app. Here is the relevant code:

## my form

```
<%= label_tag :tag_tokens, 'Tags' %>
<%= text_field_tag 'tag_tokens', "data-pre" => params[:tag_tokens] %>

 $(function() {
    $("#tag_tokens").tokenInput("/data/tags.json", {
      crossDomain: false,
      prePopulate: $("#tag_tokens").data("pre"),
      theme: "facebook"
    });
```

This is a search page that returns results. The token input along with the values returned work wonderfully. The issue I am having is getting the values to remain/load in the text box after the page is submitted. The  `"data-pre" => params[:tag_tokens]` code in the text_field_tag should handle this but no worky! Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my issue was I am using `text_field_tag` (not text_field) there for I needed to pass data-pre as the 3rd parameter (not the 2nd). Here is all my code for posterity.

## view

```
<%= label_tag :tag_tokens, 'Tags' %>
<%= text_field_tag 'tag_tokens', nil, "data-pre" => @tag_token_names.to_json %>
```

## js

```
$(function() {
    $("#tag_tokens").tokenInput("/data/tags.json", {
      crossDomain: false,
      prePopulate: $("#tag_tokens").data("pre"),
      theme: "facebook"
    });
});
</script>
```

## routes

```
match "/tags" => "data#tags", :as => 'tag_token_search'
```

## controller

```
def tags
    @tags = Tag.where("name like ?", "%#{params[:q]}%")
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render :json => @tags.map(&:attributes) }
    end
  end
```